# IIS won't display web pages on Server 2003

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-6, visual-studio-2003

When I try to load a VS 2003 project on the server itself, I get the following error.

[image]

So I attempted to run the default site and other sites in ISS and none of the pages will load. I've tried doing the aspnet_reiis -i thing and iisreset, but nothing seems to be working.

Any ideas on what I could do?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your address is not valid. Remove colon or add port like this:

```
http://localhost/valueaddTVC
```

or

```
http://localhost:80/valueaddTVC
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure where it's getting the URL, but I've typed the urls directly into the browser and it still isn't working. I tried it with port 80 and without it.